# Hiding URL in android Application

Tags: android, obfuscation

Basically one way of doing:

> ```
>  String encryptionKey =”key” String encryptedUrl =
>  “sdfghjtysdE99Qpasb8ea0w4lY8F6ZwDbRnytfrMl60= String url =
>   AESHelper.decrypt(encryptionKey, encryptedUrl); //it shall return my
>   url
> ```

However, as you see if someone willing to get the url .He can still get it  only with more work, he has to decrypt the encryptedurl  and while the obvious url is not visible this time The encryptionKey and encryptedUrl are.
I can also make it, a bit harder on him. By creating instead of encryptedUrl, multiple strings and concatenating them at the end. The obfuscated code via proguard will rename the variables and  make reading it harder.

How is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This would prove to be a waste of time at the end. Even if you could obfuscate the url in your code, it would still be visible if someone set up a network analysis tool like Wireshark. It would be better to secure your endpoints instead using authorization. You can only make the 'hackers' job harder but eventually they'll get through as you've seen.